# Assalam o alaikum. I want to ask if is it halal to earn money through youtube when you're making movie content?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, non-muslim, non-muslim-countries, movies

I actually have two youtube channels and I make movies on the games such as roblox and basically most of the viewers are non muslims. So is it permissible for me to take such cartoon film movies which does not include any adult content but moral lessons and typical love stories? Also if I film a video on christmas or any non muslim tradition but I'm not practicing it, will I be punished for this act? Please let me know... Jazakallah...

By the way, the link of my channel:
https://www.youtube.com/@CoxoSparkle

Answer (score 3):

According to what I understand, the videos you produce are prohibited since they feature love tales, boyfriends, and girlfriends. There is no need for me to provide a source to prove that it is forbidden. And this would be regarded as haram.

For non-Muslim traditions, they are also prohibited because you are participating in them, posting them online, and thus celebrating them.

Since there is a clear solution that is definitely haram, I did not cite any references. As it is haram, even though I am neither a scholar nor a shaikh, I am only sharing what I know.

Comment: Jazakallah for your answer... but the thing is I'm not the one who's earning the money so basically I don't keep the income to myself, I just simply write scripts and record videos, but not taking a single penny, would that still be haram...?

Comment: And since this is the only source of income in my family... I can't quit this work. can I at least try to pray to Allah to forgive me for this act?...

Answer (score 1):

I hear what you're saying, but you still participate. I also understand that it's your only source of income. Instead of making love stories, try making cartoons that are more kid-friendly, creative, and halal so that kids will want to watch them. You don't have to quit your job, :)

Comment: Okay, I will try my best. Jazakallah... :)